# Autocomplete not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

My autocomplete works only on the condition that the Page is reloaded. If I navigate to the page through a link this does not work. I have inluded the source code and a demo I have used. In the demo I have changed the `var data` field in order to show the values I'm fetching in the application.

Note: This is for a Ruby on Rails application.

Can someone say what is wrong with this?

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var doctors = <%== @doctors %>;

        var data = doctors.map(function (a) {
            return { label: a[0], id: a[1] };
        });

        $('#tags').autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            source: data,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $('#doctor_id').val(ui.item.id);
            }
        });
    } );


</script>
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">textsms</i>
                <label class="active" for="tags">Doctor</label>
                <input id="tags" type="text" class="autocomplete" required/>
                <input id="doctor_id" name="doctor_id" type="hidden" required/>
                </div>
              </div>
```

**Demo** : [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o7hpuz7r/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried your code with the correct scripts it runs just fine have a look

here is the head part

```
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

here is your fiddle script

```
    var data = [
    {label: "Ann Perera", id: 1},
    {label: "Sam Perera", id: 2},
    {label: "John Perera", id: 3}
    ];

    $('#tags').autocomplete({
        delay: 0,
        source: data,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $('#doctor_id').val(ui.item.label);
        }
    });
} );
```

Comment: Didnt work :( .It works fine on the fiddle. But in my Rails app it does not unless I reload the page.

Comment: mmm try to give the doctors static data instead of         var doctors = <%== @doctors %>;
does it work with the static data ?